# Entity framework & CRUD with a partial class

Tags: entity-framework-4

ASP.Net v4 page, I have setup an EntityDataSource for EF4, and am binding this to a DetailsView allowing view, edit and new for an Entity.
All works fine until I add a property to the partial class of the entity being bound:

```
namespace MyProject.EntityFramework
{
    public partial class Member
    {
        public bool CurrentMember
        {
            get
            {
                //do some stuff
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Because 'CurrentMember' is calculated there is no set for the property and I get a variety of errors when trying to either insert or update.
Adding an attribute of [ReadOnly(true)] to the property does not help, nor does setting visible to false.

This seems basic. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would say use ObjectDataSource instead and handle communication with EF by yourselves.